# Remove letters from string in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace letters with "0" from a string. But I want to remove only letters the special characters must be in string. Let's say we have variable which I mentioned below

```
var formula = "(2+b)/10";

var k = Regex.Replace(formuladetay, "[^0-9]", "0");
```

When I try this output like this

```
210
```

But I want to

```
(2+0)/10
```

Comment: Why not `formula.Replace("b", "0")`? Or, if you have multiple characters, use it in a loop.

Comment: Too much or little definition and it won't match. Something like `\p{L}` maybe ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is letters are set of english letters, use it:

```
var k = Regex.Replace(formuladetay, @"[A-Za-z]+", "0");
```

Or specify set of valid characters like you tried earlier:

```
var k = Regex.Replace(formuladetay, @"[^\d\(\)\+\-\*\/]+", "0");
```

Comment: It says Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: Instead of `@"[^\d\(\)\+\-\*\/]+"` [you can use](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5b%5e%5cd()%2b*%2f-%5d%2b&i=Something) `@"[^\d()+*/-]+"`.